# Multidimensional Data Warehouse Alternative for Reporting

Tags: sql, ssas, data-warehouse

I'm a few months into developing a reporting solution.  Currently I am loading a relational data warehouse (Fact and Dimension tables) using SSIS.  SSAS cubes and dimensions are then created from the relational Data warehouse.   I then use SSRS to build reports using MDX queries.

The problem I have is that things are starting to get rather complicated trying to understand how multidimensional modelling works as well as MDX and cubes.  Since the organization it's being designed for is rather small,  I'm thinking that I should re-evaluate my approach.

I think maybe I should just eliminate SSAS from the picture and simply create reports that report directly off the relational data warehouse using SQL queries.  The relational data warehouse could still be loaded nightly to allow up to date data for reporting.

I'm just wondering if that would be a good idea considering I'm not very experienced with data warehousing and SSAS.  Also I wanted to know if keeping my relational data warehouse in dimension and fact tables would still work with SQL queries or would I need to redesign the tables.  I don't want to make the decision to eliminate SSAS if that will end up causing more headaches or issues.

The reports will not include complicated calculations besides row counts and YTD percentages.  For example "How many callers were male?" and "How many callers called for Product A?" Which are then broken down by month.

Any comments or suggestion are much appreciated cause I'm starting to feel rather frustrated with trying get SSAS cubes developed properly.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I think I will leave SSAS out of the picture for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in a similar situation at my company. I had never used SSAS, and I was asked to do research on the benefits of using cubes to do some reporting. It was a pretty steep learning curve because my background is in development not data and reporting. SSAS is most useful when aggregate queries on a relational database are time consuming and if reports need to be broken down into hierarchies that an analyst can use to better understand the state of the business. Since SSAS stores aggregate info, queries of that nature are very quick. If your organization's data is small, the relational queries might be quick enough that you don't really need the benefit of storing aggregates.

Also you need to take into consideration the maintainability of using SSAS. If you're having trouble figuring out SSAS and MDX then how easy of a time will others? I tried to explain an MDX query I wrote to my boss who is experienced with SQL, but it's really quite different from relational queries. How easy is it going to be to add more complex reports?

A benefit to using SSAS is it can put the analyst in control of the report. Second, there are great tools and support. Finally, it's pretty easy to deploy and connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove SSAS from your architecture yes because all the results you can get from an MDX query to SSAS, you can get from a T-SQL query to your datawarehouse because the cube was built reading data from the DW. BUT, bear in mind the following: the main advantage on an OLAP cube, in my point of view, are aggregations.

Very simple explanation: lets say you have a fact table called orders with 1 million orders per month. If you want to know how much you sold on that month, using sql you need to read row by row and sum the value to produce the total. That's like 1 million reads on your DB. If you have a cube, with the propper agrregations configured, you can have that value `pre-calculated and pre-stored` on your cube so if you need to know how much you sold on a month, you will have only one read to your cube.

Its a matter of analyse your situation, if you have a small cube, maybe aggregations are not necessary and you cna do fine with SQL, but depending on the situation, they can be very helpfull